# Can I see active/pending syncs in :sync process from main process?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Is it possible to determine (from the process an app was started in) sync status for a `SyncAdapter` that is running in a separate `:sync` process? I've been toying with the standard `ContentResolver` methods below and can't get any of them to return `true` unless the code below executes in the same process as my `SyncAdapter` (the `:sync` process).

```
val currentSyncs = ContentResolver.getCurrentSyncs().any { it.authority == <authority> }
val syncPending = ContentResolver.isSyncPending(account, <authority>)
val syncActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, <authority>)
```

None of the sync framework documentation seems to indicate that this isn't possible in cross-process scenarios, so I'm a bit stumped, but it seems like the most likely explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was rather unlucky trying to find a reliable way to get sync status information from `ContentResolver`.

What worked for me: Use intents to broadcast information from your `SyncAdapter` to another component:

```
// when sync started
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(MyIntents.INTENT_ACTION_SYNC_STARTED);
context.sendBroadcast(i);

// when sync completed
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(MyIntents.INTENT_ACTION_SYNC_DONE);
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

and then receive the intents:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, 'Sync started', Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, new IntentFilter(MyIntents.INTENT_ACTION_SYNC_STARTED));
```

Comment: Yeah, we also use this method and it works great. However, I'm trying to allow an `Activity` to check current status for a sync as it's starting up, so the `Activity` doesn't necessarily have a chance to register a `BroadcastReceiver` before the sync finishes. This scenario sort of requires an on-demand approach instead of an event driven one. That said, maybe I can build a receiver that tracks sync status and is available to the activity as it's starting up.